# The browser loads the DLL file before waking up Electron

Tags: dll, electron, nsis

my electron app depends on C++ dll files. I was able to wake Electron App up in the browser, but the file it depends on is not loaded, I got `win32 error 126`. If I choose to open Electron directly by double-clicking instead of opening it from the browser, the files it depends on will load in.Everything is all right.

What's the difference between using a browser to wake up an Electron app and double-clicking to open an Electron app ?

electron-builder Version: 20.19.2

Electron Version: 2.0.18

my code:
package.json

```
"build": {
   "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "./a.dll",
        "to": "../"
      },
      {
        "from": "./c.pem",
        "to": "../"
      },
      {
        "from": "./b.dll",
        "to": "../"
      }
    ],
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true,
      "createStartMenuShortcut": true,
      "include": "script/urlProtocol.nsh"
    }
}
```

urlProtocol.nsh

```
!macro customInstall
  DetailPrint "Register voice URI Handler"
  DeleteRegKey HKCR "voice"
  WriteRegStr HKCR "voice" "" "URL:voice"
  WriteRegStr HKCR "voice" "URL Protocol" ""
  WriteRegStr HKCR "voice\shell" "" ""
  WriteRegStr HKCR "voice\shell\Open" "" ""
  WriteRegStr HKCR "voice\shell\Open\command" "" "$INSTDIR\${APP_EXECUTABLE_FILENAME} %1"
!macroend
```

a.dll、b.dll、c.pem are in the root directory of the project

Answer (score 0):

Error 126 is ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND.

You probably rely on relative paths somewhere. You don't control the current directory when your application is started so no modules should be loaded from paths starting with `./` nor `../`.

You should also quote your registered verb command correctly:

```
  WriteRegStr HKCR "voice\shell\Open\command" "" '"$INSTDIR\${APP_EXECUTABLE_FILENAME}“ “%1"'
```

Comment: After I modified it according to your method, it still made a mistake. my code use dll:`let dllPath=path.resolve(a.dll); ffi.Library(dllPath, {})`, I found that the DLL file was installed in `resources` folder.

Comment: You can't use path.resolve, you need to use path.join with the exe path.